# Decoding mp3 in windows 8.1 (universal App)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, ms-media-foundation, decoder

I'm new to C++/CX so the scenario is next:

I have a universal app windows 8.1 with c#, so I'd like to decode an mp3 from c#.
Well I know that I can Use SharpDx, but I just not what to use it, my idea is really
simple: using c++/cx and media foundation to decode mp3, and return a stream to
c#
so for example

from c#

```
Stream stream = GetMp3Stream("some.mp3"); //a custom method in c#
var audioEng = new AudioEng();   //c++/cx class
var streamOut = audioEng.DecodeMp3(stream);
```

so my problems are:

1. I dunno how using stream in c++/cx
2. I dunno how decode mp3 in c++/cx

I have found some example in cpp using ComPtr but I'd like to use cx

Comment: You had a missing `"` on the first code line. I added that for you. However, it seems this question is a bit too broad.

Comment: thanks, maybe the answer can be a simple link... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use Media Foundation for this. The [Playback-Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#playback_samples) should be a good starting point.